# Finding Energy in frequency bands of an audio file vector

Tags: matlab

I have an audio file which I imported into my Matlab workspace and have it as a vector now.

I have broken the vector into windows of 100 ms long.

```
      window_length = fs*0.1;
```

How can I find the energy in certain frequency bands. 0-1000 Hz, 1000-2000 Hz etc??

I've tried to use the filter below:

```
    % Create Filter
[N,Wc]=ellipord([450 1050]/(fs/2),[500 1000]/(fs/2),1,40);
[a,b]=ellip(N,1,40,Wc);

window_filtered=filter(a,b,window);

 % Find Filterend  Energy
Energy_band_X_X(position) =diag(window_filtered*window_filtered');
```

However my results are too large and don't make any sense.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend using a simple FFT to find the entire frequency spectrum and then finding the energy in the band of your interest. You should also normalize your input data. For example, you can divide your data by the maximum value to make them between 0 and 1. If you are dealing with 16 bits or 8 bits integer valued audio samples then your energy value is going to be high.